# RedirectMatch 301 to change part of URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

There are bad links left over from a previous error, and I'm trying to clean up my mess with 301 RedirectMatch.

Correct URLs are the following format:

```
http://www.example.com/aaa-directory/page
http://www.example.com/bbb-directory/page
http://www.example.com/ccc-directory/page
```

(etc.)

But, previously there were bad links that linked to the pages at:

```
http://www.example.com/aaa-directory//page
http://www.example.com/bbb-directory//page 
http://www.example.com/ccc-directory//page
```

(double backslash // when should be single / )

I've fixed the bad links, but I still get external links and/or robot crawls that go to those bad URLs.

I'd like to use a RedirectMatch 301 so that any link with the text "`-directory//`" will redirect to the same link with "`-directory/`".

So, `http://www.example.com/ccc-directory//page` would be redirected to:
`http://www.example.com/ccc-directory/page`

I'm struggling with the syntax.  Any help would be appreciated!

(not sure if this is needed, but my current HTACCESS file is as follows):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep redirect rules before internal rewrite ones and have another rule to take care of `//`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/+(/\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't quite work. If I enter **www.example.com/aaa-directory//page** it takes me to a fairly weird url that goes like this: **http://www.example.com/home3/username/public_html/example.com/aaa-directory/page**.  That weird URL does at least change the double backslash to a single...so maybe we're making progress?  Any further suggestions?

Comment: @JakeGould: Thanks a lot for your kind words.

Comment: @anubhava Spectacular! Works like a charm. Thank you so much. Really appreciate your help!